# Green function of a 3D wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

I was trying to find green function of a 3D wave equation using Fourier transform method. $$\left(\nabla- \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}  \right)G(\bar{x},t) = \delta(\bar{x})\delta(t)$$
Using Fourier transform $G(\bar{x},t)=1/(2\pi)^4 \int dw\:d^3k\:exp(-i\bar{k}\bar{x}-iwt)G(k,w) $
$$G(k,w)=\frac{1}{w^2-k^2}$$
Then we can perform integration by angles and reach this integral
$$G(x,t)=\frac{1}{x}\int \frac{2k \sin(k x)}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{e^{-i w t}}{w^2-k^2}dw\:dk$$
However i have a problem with integration by variable $w$ because my poles are lying on a real axis and i don't know how to chose my path correctly. Is there some way to chose contour to get a right answer?Maybe there are some properties of green functions that allows me to chose it?

I was thinking about adding to my equation some damping term
$$\left(\nabla- \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\gamma \frac{\partial}{\partial t}  \right)G(\bar{x},t) = \delta(\bar{x})\delta(t)$$
Then $$G(x,t)=\frac{1}{x}\int \frac{2k \sin(k x)}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{e^{-i w t}}{w^2-k^2+iw \gamma}dw\:dk$$
If $\gamma=+0$ two my poles are in $Im(w)<0$ but i don't get a right answer
$$G(x,t)=-\frac{\delta(x-t)}{2\pi x}$$

Comment: Shouldn't Green's function depend on four variables in this case? $G(x,x',t,t')$ so the right hand side of the first equation is $\delta(x-x') \delta(t-t')$? Also, if this is $3D$ equation, is $x$ a vector? Or the absolute value? In that case the right hand side should be $ \frac{1}{2 \pi x}\delta(x-x') \delta(t-t')$, I think

Comment: Yes,but i used homogeneity to define $G(x-x',t-t')=G1(x,x',t,t')$. Variable without bar means absolute value.

Comment: Re write the equations without assuming c = 1.  Might help clear things up. Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657204/greens-function-for-the-3d-wave-equation?rq=1